# When the list view is clicked, the application crashes! Why?

Tags: java, android, contacts

I have created a list view. And have added a 'OnItemClickListener()' to it. I am passing an intent and passing some data through the intent.

```
 contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactInfo.class);
            Contact ParseContactID = contactAdapter.getItem(position);

            intent.putExtra("ParseContactID", (Parcelable) ParseContactID);

            startActivity(intent);
     }
 });
```

And I am retrieving the data in another class.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle cBundle = intent.getExtras();

    String ContactInfo = cBundle.getString("ParseContactID");
```

But the app crashes when I try and click the any lists. Here is the [image of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9EgK.png) and [app crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvFke.png)

The log cat has some fatal errors don't know how to fix those.

```
04-18 10:33:22.547 3528-3528/cm0573.contactsapp.user.contactsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: cm0573.contactsapp.user.contactsapp, PID: 3528
                                                                               java.lang.ClassCastException: cm0573.contactsapp.user.contactsapp.Contact cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
                                                                                   at cm0573.contactsapp.user.contactsapp.MainActivity$4.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

HELP!

Comment: What is unclear about the Exception message:  `java.lang.ClassCastException: cm0573.contactsapp.user.contactsapp.Contact cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable`?

Comment: Are you trying to send a `Contact` or a `String`? Your code tries one but expects the other.

Comment: I recently added the parselable. The error was before I added that.

Comment: I am trying to send a contact via putExtra method. There is a error which I don't completely understand. The error says "cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, Contact)'."

Comment: Your `Contact` needs to implement `Parcelable` then. And in your receiving class you need to do `cBundle.getParcelable` not `getString` https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting a `Contact` object into the Extra but when you are extracting, you are trying to get a `String`. A `Contact` object and `String` object are not the same. Right?

You can make your Contact class implement the `Serializable` interface and after that, you can do this.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("ParseContactID", ParseContactID);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Retrieving the data in another class

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Contact  contact = (Contact)bundle.getSerializable("ParseContactID");
```

Or if you want to implement `parcelable` you can read [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

```
public class ContactInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView ContactInfoFamily_Name;
TextView ContactInfoFirst_Name;
TextView ContactInfoHouse_Number_ ;
TextView ContactInfoStreet_Name;
TextView ContactInfoTown_;
TextView ContactInfoCounty_;
TextView ContactInfoPost_Code;
TextView ContactInfoPhone_Number;
DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_info);

    ContactInfoFamily_Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoFamilyName);
    ContactInfoFirst_Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoFirstName);
    ContactInfoHouse_Number_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoHouseNumber);
    ContactInfoStreet_Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoStreetName);
    ContactInfoTown_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoTown);
    ContactInfoCounty_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoCounty);
    ContactInfoPost_Code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoPostCode);
    ContactInfoPhone_Number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoPhone);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle cBundle = intent.getExtras();

    Contact ContactInfo = (Contact) cBundle.getSerializable("ParseContactID");

    ContactInfoFamily_Name.setText(ContactInfo.getID());
    ContactInfoFirst_Name.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("FirstNameKey"));
    ContactInfoHouse_Number_.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("HouseNumberKey"));
    ContactInfoStreet_Name.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("StreetNameKey"));
    ContactInfoTown_.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("TownKey"));
    ContactInfoCounty_.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("CountyKey"));
    ContactInfoPost_Code.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("TownKey"));
    ContactInfoPhone_Number.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("PhoneNumberKey"));


}
}
```

Comment: I did the exact things you said. Now the logcat is giving me null pointer exceptions on multiple lines

Comment: Check if your Contact object is null or not. Can you show me your log ?

Comment: Have you added your other activity (ContactInfo.class) in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes I have. It was auto generated though.  <activity android:name=".ContactInfo"></activity>

Comment: Well, this is not happening because of Serializable. Can you post your ContactInfo class?

Comment: I am uploading. please check answers.

Comment: Take your all TextView initialization into `OnCreate()` and put them under `setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_info);` this line.

Comment: Now logcat is displaying 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cm0573.contactsapp.user.contactsapp/cm0573.contactsapp.user.contactsapp.ContactInfo}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1'

Comment: have you set all those keys, from where you are getting data, like `getIntent().getExtras().getString("FirstNameKey")`

Comment: The exceptions keep on changing. Now its giving me the null pointer exception again.

Comment: I had tried some trial and error code but most of the code in there is dummy and doesn't work. I have to add keys and use the functions I declared in the Contact class.

Comment: It's really hard to find problem like this. I would suggest that, at first try to open your `ContactInfo` activity. comment out all the lines after `setContentView()` method and see if you can open the activity.

Comment: The application was starting the new activity at first. But then suddenly stopped working and hasn't been working since then.

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Contact` made it implements `Serializable`.

```
public class Contact implements Serializable{ 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your `Contact` class implements `Parcelable`.

   ```
   public class Contact implements Parcelable {

       ...........
       ............... 
   }
   ```
2. Send `Contact` to `ContactInfo` Activity as below:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactInfo.class);
   Contact contact = contactAdapter.getItem(position);

   intent.putExtra("ParseContactID", contact);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
3. Retrieving the `Contact` in `ContactInfo` Activity.

   ```
   Contact contact = (Contact) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("ParseContactID");
   ```

Here is good [Tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable) about using `Parcelable`.

Hope this will help~

Comment: I implemented serializable but now the logcat is giving me a nullpointer exception. [IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/4gj6sg.png[/IMG]

Comment: Can you please post your contact class?

Comment: which part do you want? I can upload all of it.

Comment: post "Contact" class where you implement Serializable

Answer (score 0):

ContactInfo class -

```
package cm0573.contactsapp.user.contactsapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView ContactInfoFamily_Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoFamilyName);
TextView ContactInfoFirst_Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoFirstName);
TextView ContactInfoHouse_Number_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoHouseNumber);
TextView ContactInfoStreet_Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoStreetName);
TextView ContactInfoTown_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoTown);
TextView ContactInfoCounty_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoCounty);
TextView ContactInfoPost_Code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoPostCode);
TextView ContactInfoPhone_Number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactInfoPhone);
DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_info);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle cBundle = intent.getExtras();

    Contact ContactInfo = (Contact) cBundle.getSerializable("ParseContactID");

    ContactInfoFamily_Name.setText(ContactInfo.getID());
    ContactInfoFirst_Name.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("FirstNameKey"));
    ContactInfoHouse_Number_.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("HouseNumberKey"));
    ContactInfoStreet_Name.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("StreetNameKey"));
    ContactInfoTown_.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("TownKey"));
    ContactInfoCounty_.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("CountyKey"));
    ContactInfoPost_Code.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("TownKey"));
    ContactInfoPhone_Number.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("PhoneNumberKey"));


}
}
```